# MySQL + Sequelize - tables was created with a capital letter, but Sequelize generate query with a lower letter

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have such Sequelize migration:

```js
await queryInterface.createTable("Organizations", { ...
```

but in some moments the Sequelize generated request in this way:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `organizations`...
```

with a lower letter and I get the next error:

> ERROR: Table 'db_name.organizations' doesn't exist

How can I fix this behavior?

With all this, my colleagues have no such problem.

Comment: I use latest MySQL docker on Mac M1

Comment: For this precise reason (and others.), good practice would be to never use uppercase letters in sql. https://www.sqlstyle.guide/

Answer (score 0):

Sequlize models have 2 options that can help you.

1. tableName https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#providing-the-table-name-directly
2. freezeTableName https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#enforcing-the-table-name-to-be-equal-to-the-model-name

`tableName` allows you to set the table name to be used and `freezeTableName` will freeze the name set in the model